# Calculating average of variable data size using VBA and Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have task to upload multiple text files to multiple sheets and calculate average below that data.Some text files have 200 rows and some have 5 rows with 
different number of data in each row.I have succesfully separate each file but i cannot make function average.Example of txt file: https://ufile.io/7ii41

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim Rws As Long
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim FrNg As Range
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Open", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Error"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
    I = 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    xTempWb.Close False
    xWb.Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=True, Space:=False, _
      Other:=False
      lRow = Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                    after:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
     average=??

    Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        I = I + 1
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        With xWb
            xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=True, Space:=False, _
              Other:=False
        End With
        lRow = Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                    after:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    average=??

    Loop

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: Outputs are: https://ufile.io/7rihc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two quick functions that you could add to your workbook that can calculate the average of a column.

```
Private Function ColumnAvg(colRng As Range)

    ColumnAvg = 0
    On Error Resume Next

    ColumnAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns(colRng.Column)) / _ 
                Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(colRng.Column))

End Function

Private Function RowAvg(rowRng As Range)

    RowAvg = 0
    On Error Resume Next

    RowAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rows(rowRng.Row)) / _ 
             Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(rowRng.Row))

End Function
```

NOte: These are marked as private functions as they will calculate the ENTIRE column or row. These functions are meant to be called within VBA, not within the spreedsheet. Make sure you place these functions within the same module.

Example of code:

1 - `x = ColumnAvg(Range("A1"))`

2 - `x = ColumnAvg(Range("A:A"))`

3 - `x = ColumnAvg(Cells(1,1))`

If you are wanting to calculate the entire worksheet's average, then you could use this function...

```
Private Function AvgEverything()
Dim Text As String

    Text = "A1:" & Split(Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).Address(True, False), "$")(0) _ 
                 & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
    AvgEverything = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Text)) / _
                    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Text))

End Function
```

Comment: I need to calculate average of all the number,not row by row

Comment: I just updated the above answer to include a third macro for calculating the entire worksheet.